# How can I tell how close I am to death?

Tags: silent-hill-3

I'm playing through Silent Hill 3 on  the Silent Hill HD Collection, and although I've gathered that the "status" image in the top left corner indicates my health, the manual doesn't contain any information on how to actually read the image itself.

How can I tell how much health I have in Silent Hill 3?

Comment: Heather also visibly looks worse for wear when she's about to die and I think walks slower...but I can't verify that with no more PS2